# Footer knocked out by 1px in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Heres the link:

[DAMNIE6TOHELL](http://tinyurl.com/596xva)

As you can see if viewed in glorious 'IE6-o-color', the footer is shifting 1px over to the left.
I'm struggling to find a fix for this, I've whittled it down to a bare minimum of HTML.

Is it something to do with haslayout perhaps? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: An image of the bug for those that don't have IE6 would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
background-position: 50% top;
```

to the css of container_bottom.

It works for me with IE Developer toolbar, but it's on a IE6 Virtual machine, so I'm not sure about real world results

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it's a case of the [IE6 1px jog](http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/onepxjog.htm) which can be solved by a few different fixes.

You will only want to apply these fixes to IE6, using your favourite method (conditional comments, star html hack, whatever). You could

- apply background position to #container_bottom

  container_bottom { background-position:1px 0; }
- apply a left margin or padding to #container_bottom

  container_bottom { margin-left:1px; }
- or float #container_bottom to the left and give it a width

  container_bottom { float:left; width:800px; }

Any of those seemed to work for me.